# how to make element in a Xml schema as optinal

Tags: xml, xsd

I have one element that I need to make optional.

```
<xs:element name="Version" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
```

Is there any other way than making `minOccurs="0"`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that is the proper way to do it.  Is there some reason why you wish to avoid `minOccurs="0"`?

Comment: No. I thought there might be any other possibility.

Answer (score 2):

`minOccurs="0"` *is* the way to specify optional